# Is it possible to test an iPhone web application over an ad hoc wireless network?

Tags: iphone, macos, networking, wifi

I'm working on a web application that will have a custom UI for the iPhone platform. At the moment I have my Apple laptop but I'm away from a wired or wi-fi Internet connection. I want to run the app on the laptop and then preview it on the iPhone. Is this possible?

I created an ad hoc wireless (AirPort) connection on the Mac and could join it successfully from my iPhone, but when I tried to access the app using its *host.local:port* address in Mobile Safari it couldn't see it. I have Web sharing enabled on the Mac.

Comment: Did you try typing the IP address of the Mac instead?

Comment: It doesn't work and strangely I don't get the wi-fi icon in the status bar on the iPhone when in Mobile Safari, even though it's joined the ad hoc network OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my company we made test in local via a wifi router and it works fine.

If your machine IP is 192.168.1.3 for example you have to use this IP to make the connection from your iPhone to your Mac.

Comment: This works, but only if you go via a wireless router. Also, it only seems to work if you're serving the application through the Mac's built-in Apache web server.